# Undo step with IdaPython?

Tags: ida, idapython

With Ida I can press Control+Z to undo the last action

Can I do that with IdaPython?

Comment: You probably should describe what you *actually* want to achieve and why you think undo is the answer.

Answer (score 1):

No.  Only interactive user actions can be undone via the UI or keyboard shortcut.